# How to add a default folder always with target installation using NSIS

Tags: nsis

I want to append a default directory to my INSTALL directory always internally.
I have set it by default but if user change the directory then it not works and installed the files in the folder that user selected.

So I need append a folder ( Product name ) always internally and it can be append with the user's selected path.

Like if user selected "C:\Program Files\My Folder" then the installation should be in path "C:\Program Files\My Folder\ProductName"
Should work with the silent as well.
Can someone please advise on this.

Comment: I would be very upset if a installer did this to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Section MyFirstSection
StrCpy $InstDir "$InstDir\ProductName" ; Force extra sub-directory
; ...
SectionEnd
```

However, the recommended way to do this is to just use [`InstallDir`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#ainstalldir) without a ending backslash:

> Note that the part of this string following the last \ will be used if the user selects 'browse', and may be appended back on to the string at install time (to disable this, end the directory with a \ (which will require the entire parameter to be enclosed with quotes).